# How does rails 4 know which manifest file to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

There used to be a single `manifest.yml` file.  Now we have multiple `manifest-*.json` files.  How does rails know which one to use?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Sprockets source, it just picks the first one.  See line 50 here: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb